# Splitting user input address with a comma

Tags: flutter, mobile

so I'm new to flutter. Was trying to separate the address displayed with comma.

Am I missing something?
Here's my code:

```
 Widget buildUserAddress() {
var adr = address;
adr.toString().split(',').reversed.toList();
return Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20),
  child: Text(
    adr,
    maxLines: 3,
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 15,
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "adr" is of type list, so you need to give the index to get the value.
You can do something like this inside your buildUserAddress().

```
Widget buildUserAddress(String getAddress) {
 List adrList = getAddress.toString().split(',').reversed.toList();
 return Container(
   width: double.infinity,
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20),
   child: ListView.builder(
     itemCount: adrList.length,
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
       return Text("${adrList[index]}");
     },
    ),
  );
}
```